# Is there a Shortcut in Pycharm or Sublime Text 2 for Jump out of matching brackets?

Tags: pycharm, sublimetext

Is there a shortcut in Pycharm or Sublime Text 2 for jumping out of matching brackets and `"` or `'` pairs?

Now I out it by press left, agony.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I did it in Sublime:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true} }
```

Shift-Enter breaks out of quotes and brackets, and Super-Enter creates a new line without breaking the current one

Comment: great one. Real cool setting. Thank you Nick. << To StackOverflow: I know this section is not for saying thanks. I admire stackoverflow. Still we can't express this in a single upvote >>

Answer (score 9):

In Sublime Text 2, Ctrl+M works for () and [].

Comment: yes on Mac it's ctrl+m too not cmd+m. 
See https://gist.github.com/nuxlli/1207014

Comment: it works for braces too since your brace is underlined, otherwise it won't work. Weird fact is sometimes you can't even jump back to the matching brace which you come from :/

Comment: It jumps back to matching bracket... Not out of it. I guess that's not what this question wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific shortcut for this in PyCharm. You can use Ctrl-Left/Right (this works for word-by-word navigation in all contexts), or use Ctrl-W to extend the selection to the range you need and then press Left or Right to jump out of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin called "BracketHighlighter". Besides of highlighting brackets and quotes, it supports a bracket jumping by pressing Alt+Up/Alt+Down. Quite handy.