# Sublime Text 3 : auto replace parentheses

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text 3, I love the feature that correspond to this :

```
// Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
    "auto_match_enabled": true
```

in Preferences.

The problem is, when I have something like this :

```
var_dump('Final link : '.$type);
```

and I want something like this :

```
var_dump('Final link : '.($type?$type:'false');
```

I have to close my right parenthesis BUT it just write OVER the existing one and I have to do it two times so my caret is AFTER the existing right parenthesis.

I want to keep the "auto pairing" feature but not this one and I can't find anything about it, is it possible ?

Comment: `var_dump('Final link : '.($type?$type:'false');` is missing a final `)`.

Comment: Did you check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032041/how-to-prevent-sublime-text-2-from-swallowing-closing-brackets-quotes-and-paren ? I know it's for version 2, but unless they changed how the settings worked, it should still apply.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you, works perfectly ! It was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your code to be

```
var_dump('Final link : '.($type?$type:'false'));
```

as you are missing a closing `)` in your question. If this is the case, if you're starting from:

```
var_dump('Final link : '.$type);
```

place your cursor just after the `.`, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to select `$type`:

[image: $type selected]

Next, just type an opening parenthesis <kbd>(</kbd>, and the selected text will be surrounded with opening and closing parentheses:

[image: ($type)]

Finally, hit <kbd>→</kbd> to place the cursor after the `e` in `$type`, and you can begin entering the rest of the expression.

Comment: It should indeed works, but that's not really "my style" of writing (it might be a good habit to do this though : faster), [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032041/how-to-prevent-sublime-text-2-from-swallowing-closing-brackets-quotes-and-paren) was a nice other way to do it.